# Is there any other alternative available to get ImageView and convert it into Bitmap for image classification in android?

Tags: android, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite

I want to get Bitmap from `ImageView`. I have used the followin code, but it throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundExcpetion`. How to solve this ?

```
 bitmap.getPixels(mImagePixels, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0,
                    bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

            int pixel = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < DIM_IMG_SIZE_WIDTH; ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < DIM_IMG_SIZE_HEIGHT; ++j) {
                    final int val = mImagePixels[pixel++];
                    mImgData.putFloat(convertToGreyScale(val));
                }
            }

        }
        private float convertToGreyScale(int color) {
            return (((color >> 16) & 0xFF) + ((color >> 8) & 0xFF) + (color & 0xFF)) / 3.0f / 255.0f;
        }

     java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.checkPixelsAccess(Bitmap.java:1824)
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.getPixels(Bitmap.java:1765)
            at com.drprajapati.android.plantclassification.ml.Classifier.convertBitmapToByteBuffer(Classifier.java:69)
            at com.drprajapati.android.plantclassification.ml.Classifier.classify(Classifier.java:53)
            at com.drprajapati.android.plantclassification.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:58)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6671)
            at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6640)
            at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:791)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26173)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6912)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: You can use `BitmapFactory` if it's convenient in your case (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider trying this

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the image from ImageView in drawable form and then convert drawable into a bitmap by passing drawable into the following method.

```
public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
Bitmap bitmap = null;

if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
    if(bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
        return bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
    }
}

if(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Single color 
bitmap will be created of 1x1 pixel
} else {
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), 
drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
}

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
drawable.draw(canvas);
return bitmap;
}
```